# Preview Entire Document Typed in Textarea in New Window

Tags: javascript, html, window, document, overwrite

I'm making a simple code editor for writing HTML/CSS/JS files online and offline.
So far, everything is going great, but I'm trying to figure out how to accurately preview a full HTML document that is typed into the editor, doctype and all. So far for the editor, you can use "Open in New Tab" to open the document you type into a new window.

However, the only way I got it to work the way I want it to made me use a base64 encoded HTML file, which allowed me to output an ENTIRE document to a window, doctype and all.

If I used say, `previewWinRef.document.write(editor.value)`, that wouldn't work. After trying it, all it did was append to the current document.

How can I clear the contents of the preview window of its entirety and write the entire value of the editor textarea to the preview window WITHOUT using base64 encoding?

[EDIT]:
Here is what is happening in the code:

```
editor.addEventListener('keydown',function(event){
            setTimeout(function(){
                if(previewWinRef){
                    previewWinRef.location = "data:text/html;base64,"+Base64.encode(editor.value);
                }
            },100);
        });
```

Basically I'm refreshing the result every time you push a key down, ONLY if you opened the preview window by going to File->Open In New Tab. For some reason, I can't seem to be able to access the document of the preview window, even though editor window created it and it's just a data URL? *Window{}* [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZF1Y.jpg)

[Here is the editor.](http://rickyyoder.x10.mx/html5/editor.html)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var win = window.open("about:blank", "title");
win.document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].innerHTML = document.body.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value;
```

Comment: I was thinking this too, but I'd like it to be valid HTML. You can't just have a doctype and another HTML tag inside another element.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't think of any other way to do this without a POST to some server.

Answer (score 0):

Original answer updated.

You can use the `documentElement` property of the document object from the new tab. The catch here is that some browsers will complain about a same-origin-policy violation if the domain of the new tab's `window.location` is set to another site (or in your case a data string).

```
previewWinRef = window.open("about:blank");
previewWinRef.document.documentElement.innerHTML = editor.value;
```

Comment: Tried this. Couldn't access it cause of same origin policy. That's weird.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you post the event handler you are trying to use when you got the cross origin error?

Comment: Yes, I will once I get home. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem in Firefox (the only browser I have on my work computer). I wonder if Chrome and Firefox implement the same origin policy slightly differently? I will play around with it tonight from a computer running Chrome.

Comment: Also, you might try opening the second window with `window.open("http://rickyyoder.x10.mx/")`. That should force the two tabs to have the same domain...

Comment: Yes. I created a separate file for previewing. I'm currently trying to solve the problem using a copy of the file, so I don't mess your research up. Is there a way to overwrite a window using document.write() instead of appending to it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64281/discussion-between-warren-r-and-rickyayoder).